# Как обновлять/проверять пакеты автоматически?

Tags: laravel, composer

Есть несколько проектов. Все они обновляют товары по одному поставщику. Парсеры оформлены в виде пакетов и можно обновиться через composer.

Поставщик вносит изменения в свое api.
И тут каждому на сервер нужно заходить в консоль и обновлять.
Много лишних действий.

Как заставить обновляться их автоматически?
Как должно работать на мой взгляд:

1. В очереди по расписанию выполняется проверка на наличие обновлений и
   запуск обновления.
2. Запуск/проверка обновления по кнопке из админ панели.
3. Было бы очень неплохо видеть прогресс из админ панели.

Вопросы:
Как чекнуть пакеты?
Как запустить обновления автоматом или по кнопке?

Кто сталкивался с такой задачей?
Может есть готовые решения по этой теме?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовал следующим образом. 
С центрального сайта идет запрос на обновление по кнопке. На принимающей стороне запускается обновление через exec в очереди. Передаем на обновление только свои пакеты. Результат пишется в файл и отправляется на центральный сайт.